# how to make a mutilple index in ES API Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

my index is : `https://URL/bpa_stag_v3_2016*,bpa_stag_v3_2017/orders_suppliers_stats_ag/_search`
i'm using the api java for Elastic search , and it didn't work .

```
  String indexForTwoYear = ConfiguratorDao.CURRENT_ENV.getAliasPrefix() + String.valueOf(previousYear) + "*,"
                    + ConfiguratorDao.CURRENT_ENV.getAliasPrefix() + String.valueOf(currentYear) + "*";



            SearchRequestBuilder requestBuilder = client.prepareSearch(indexForTwoYear)
                    .setTypes(IndexTypeEnum.SUPPLIERS_AGGREGATION.getValue()).setQuery(queryBuilder).setSize(1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation of `AbstractClient` class of Elasticsearch (which is extended by `NodeClient` and `TransportClient`), you can pass variable number of indices as var-args in `prepareSearch` method (javadoc [here](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/2.3.0)):

```
public SearchRequestBuilder prepareSearch(String... indices)
```

> Search across one or more indices and one or more types with a query.

So, in your case, it would be:

```
client.prepareSearch("pa_stag_v3_2016*","bpa_stag_v3_2017")
```

Comment: can you please correct your answer for the index bpa_stag_v3_2016* with * because my index's are dynamic so i need all the index in 2016 and 2017

Comment: @YasBES Done, try now?

Answer (score 1):

To search across multiple indexes using the Java API, you should just pass the index names as multiple parameters (and not as a single comma-separated string...)

Like this: `client.prepareSearch("bpa_stag_v3_2016*", "bpa_stag_v3_2017")`

See example here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-search.html.

Comment: can you please correct your answer for the index bpa_stag_v3_2016* with * because my index's are dynamic so i need all the index in 2016 and 2017